# sending calendar request through mail

Tags: php, email, calendar

I am trying to implement the calendar request mail through my php code. My code is like :

```
$to = "srimanta.chakraborty@fugenx.com";
$subject = "Training Registration";
$message = "Thank you for participating in the Technical Certification training program.";
$location = "Conf";
//==================
$headers = "Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8";
$messaje = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR";
$messaje .= "VERSION:2.0";
$messaje .= "PRODID:PHP";
$messaje .= "METHOD:REQUEST";
$messaje .= "BEGIN:VEVENT";
$messaje .= "DTSTART:20121223T171010Z";
$messaje .= "DTEND:20121223T191010Z";
$messaje . "DESCRIPTION: You have registered for the class";
$messaje .= "SUMMARY:Technical Training";
$messaje .= "ORGANIZER; CN=\"Corporate\":mailto:jayashree.g@fugenx.com";
$messaje .= "Location:" . $location . "";
$messaje .= "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000006FC30E6 C39DC004CA782E0C002E01A81\n";
$messaje .= "SEQUENCE:0\n";
$messaje .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\n";
$messaje .= "END:VEVENT\n";
$messaje .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";
$headers .= $messaje;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

By this code I got mail but not in terms of calendar request format. Also mail has been forwarded along with an attachment "Training Registration.ics" file.
I need the Accept, Tentative, Decline, Propose New Time, Calendar option along with the mail.
Please guide me how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I'd post what appear to be valid e-mail addresses in your code here.

Comment: Consider using a modern PHP mailing library, like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer, to handle attachments for you.  As you see now, rolling your own MIME is a *pain*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$headers = 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n';
```

Here, try to change single quote to double quote('=>")

It is because dingle quote will escape \r and \n
[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

**Update**
Finally, I do the suggestion in below and change your header and, at least, it work on my side.

```
$to = "srimanta.chakraborty@fugenx.com";
$subject = "Training Registration";
$message = "Thank you for participating in the Technical Certification training program.\r\n\r\n";
$location = "Conf";
//==================
$headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$messaje = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$messaje .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$messaje .= "PRODID:PHP\r\n";
$messaje .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$messaje .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$messaje .= "DTSTART:20121223T171010Z\r\n";
$messaje .= "DTEND:20121223T191010Z\r\n";
$messaje .= "DESCRIPTION: You have registered for the class\r\n";
$messaje .= "SUMMARY:Technical Training\r\n";
$messaje .= "ORGANIZER; CN=\"Corporate\":mailto:jayashree.g@fugenx.com\r\n";
$messaje .= "Location:" . $location . "\r\n";
$messaje .= "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000006FC30E6 C39DC004CA782E0C002E01A81\r\n";
$messaje .= "SEQUENCE:0\r\n";
$messaje .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
$messaje .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$messaje .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$message .= $messaje;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: actually, the above answer assume the code could send calender~_~  I have no idea on how to send calender through email @@a

Comment: After changing this single quote to double quote I got the following issue:

 ORGANIZER; CN="Corporate":mailto:srimanta12@gmail.com
Location:
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000006FC30E6 C39DC004CA782E0C002E01A81 SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20121228T002344
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Thank you for participating in the Technical Certification training program.

Also in the header section I got another message like "Extra line breaks in this message were removed." And I did not get any Accept link or Tentavive link for that email.

Comment: where does your code come from? I am not sure how to send calender through email and have no time to do research right now since I am in office :-) However, my next suggestion is check if you should put $messaje in the $headers

Comment: Also, I guess you can try change all \n to \r\n

Comment: Oh....$messaje . "DESCRIPTION: You have registered for the class\n"; you miss = here, and for the above message, I mean I think $messaje should be put in $message

Comment: I have to work now, leave a message here if you still unable to solve the problem, I will get back to you after 2-3 hrs

Comment: Okay please ceck when you will get time. Still no output for me.

Comment: Meeting timing, Accept/Tentative/Decline button are not showing. I have edited my code also.

Comment: I have the same issue as @phpdeveloper it is not showing tAccept/Tentative/Decline buttons. I am checking in outlook.com.