# ICS email attachment in PHP

Tags: php, icalendar, gcal

I need to send an .ics event file to Gmail - not as an attachment, but with the option to add the corresponding event to a calendar as a calendar request.
So that the user can add the event to google calendar. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065957/sending-calendar-request-through-mail) here on SO that deals with sending calendar requests via mail.

Comment: I have used the code,but I am receiving the invite.ics file as attachment.

Comment: [This discussion](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17828/guidelines-on-email-formatting-to-make-contents-google-calendar-friendly) proposes to use specific keywords like `where:`, `when:` or `location:` to trigger [Google's Automatic event recognition](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/47802).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code, it just send an email as an attachment, I don't see Accept/Add to google calendar options.

```
$headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$messaje = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$messaje .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$messaje .= "PRODID:PHP\r\n";
$messaje .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$messaje .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$messaje .= "DTSTART:20121223T171010Z\r\n";
$messaje .= "DTEND:20121223T191010Z\r\n";
$messaje .= "DESCRIPTION: You have registered for the class\r\n";
$messaje .= "SUMMARY:Technical Training\r\n";
$messaje .= "ORGANIZER; CN=\"Corporate\":mailto:test@gmail.com\r\n";
$messaje .= "Location:" . $location . "\r\n";
$messaje .= "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000006FC30E6 C39DC004CA782E0C002E01A81\r\n";
$messaje .= "SEQUENCE:0\r\n";
$messaje .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
$messaje .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$messaje .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$message .= $messaje;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an ATTENDEE property corresponding to the user you are sending the invitation to. See [Outlook fails to recognize an ics message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812438/outlook-fails-to-recognize-an-ics-message/21823970#21823970)